# Java CLASSPATH asked in ocjp

Tags: classpath

A UNIX user named Bob wants to replace his chess program with a new one, but he is not sure where the old one is installed. Bob is currently able to run a Java chess program starting from his home directory /home/bob using the command: java -classpath /test:/home/bob/downloads/*.jar games.Chess Bob's CLASSPATH is set (at login time) to: /usr/lib:/home/bob/classes:/opt/java/lib:/opt/java/lib/*.jar What is a possible location for the Chess.class file?

```
/test/Chess.class 
/home/bob/Chess.class 
/test/games/Chess.class 
/usr/lib/games/Chess.class 
/home/bob/games/Chess.class 
inside jarfile /opt/java/lib/Games.jar (with a correct manifest) 
inside jarfile /home/bob/downloads/Games.jar (with a correct manifest)
```

please answer this question

Answer (score 3):

Only this is the answer:

```
(3)    /test/games/Chess.class
```

Because when you specify -classpath you override **CLASSPATH** from the OS for this execution. And they say that "*Bob is currently able to run a Java chess program* " so the new version is not in the CLASSPATH but in the path specified by Bob. So only (3) is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Classpath loading always seemed tricky for me, I hope that my answer is correct.

- /test/Chess.class - **no**, `Chess` class must be inside `games` package
- /home/bob/Chess.class - **no**, same as above
- /test/games/Chess.class - **yes**
- /usr/lib/games/Chess.class - **yes**
- /home/bob/games/Chess.class - **no**, `/home/bob` is not added to classpath
- inside jarfile /opt/java/lib/Games.jar (with a correct manifest) - **no**, `/opt/java/lib/.jar` - cp can not be defined this way; correct path: `/opt/java/lib/*`
- inside jarfile /home/bob/downloads/Games.jar (with a correct manifest) - **no**, same as above